# Web3 Transaction working on Metamask but not on Trust wallet

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets, trust

I have the following code for a bnb transaction, which is working on metamask, but now on trust wallet

```
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
      try {
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        initPayButton()
      } catch (err) {
        $('#status').html('User denied account access', err)
      }
    } else if (window.ethereum) {
  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
} else {
  // Code for HttpProvider remains unchanged
}
await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
  })

  const initPayButton = () => {
    $('#PayButton').click(() => {
      // paymentAddress is where funds will be send to
      const paymentAddress = 'MyWallet'
      const amountEth = 0.05*document.getElementById('Q1').value

      web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: ethereum.selectedAddress,
        gas: gas,
        gasLimit: gasLimit,
        to: paymentAddress,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(String(amountEth), 'ether')
      }, (err, transactionId) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Payment failed', err)
          $('#status').html('Payment failed')
        } else {
          console.log('Payment successful', transactionId)
          $('#status').html('Payment successful')
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

Could someone help me to find why it is working on metamask but no on trust wallet?

Answer (score 0):

I found on [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3.html#setprovider).

Try this

```
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

*change

`http://localhost:8584`

with your RPCurl like:

```
https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/
```

or you can use [walletconnect](https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/web3-provider)